# my project is online book shopping

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2008

i am using multiple textboxes in webform and i would to validate each textbox by one validator in which validation like as any textbox does not empty and check the datatype of the input string.For this what of validator i can use and how?

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery.Validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) is a good one for client side validation and [DataAnnotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx) can be useful for server side validation.